# How to call a method from a jar file in Java

Tags: java, jar

1. Are all files in the jar file .class which cannot be viewed by a text editor or IDE?
2. If they are all class files, how then,do we know how it works and what the methods look like? Does the creator of the jar write a documentation to it?

I have created a jar file with Netbeans  using this simple example.  How do I extend the jar in another java file and use the methods of the super class?

```
class Animal {
 void eat() {
 System.out.println("animal : eat");
  }
void anotherEat()
  {
 System.out.println("dog : eat from parents");
  }

}

  class Dog extends Animal {
  void eat() {
  System.out.println("dog : eat");
  }
  void sleep ()
  {

}

void anotherEat() {
System.out.println("dog : eat from child");
 // super.eat();
  }
  }

 public class EatingContest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Animal a = new Animal();
   a.eat();
   Dog d = new Dog();
   d.eat();
   //Animal e = new Dog();
   //e.eat();
   Dog f = new Dog();
   f.anotherEat();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you know how to use `import` statements? Also keep in mind if you created the classes in the jar, in the default package, you will not be able to import it.

Comment: Yes..I know. What happens then? How do you know the implementation since you cannot see anything in the class files?

Comment: Good libraries will have good documentation. For [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). The Javadoc should explain the basic API methods available. Normally, with libraries, your main concern should not be the implementation. It should be focused on the contract.

Comment: I see. So in essence, there should be a documentation file as to the methods and what they accept, etc...

Comment: Yes. Do some research on how to write Javadoc comments. Netbeans is capable of creating the Javadoc like you saw in the link, from your code. You don't have to create it yourself. The javadoc tool will use your comments to create it

Comment: Once imported, it works similar to inheritance?

Comment: No, not at all. Inheritence is when you extends a class. `import` just means that you will be using the class inside the importing class. have you ever worked with packages? like `com.foo.MyClass`. If you wanted to use that class in say `hello.world.Bar` class, you would need to `import com.foo.MyClass` inside of `hello.world.Bar`, so you can use it

Comment: Great. I get the understanding. I've imported packages and libraries but never thought of what was happening behind. :)

Comment: If all else fails, you can rename the .jar file with the .zip extension and treat it thusly.  Sometimes you can glean otherwise missing information from that.  (And actually, you don't *have* to import to use a class, you can refer it by its fully qualified name instead.)